# Creating a sublist from a parent list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a collection of custom objects, dependents. The custom object has about 70 properties. I want to extract just one property, the membernumber. I have the following code, where I am extracting the membernumbers and creating another list:

```
var memberIDs = (from d in dependents
                            select new
                                   {
                                       d.MemberNum 
                                   });
            foreach(var id in memberIDs)
            {
                string idValue = id.ToString();
            }
```

The problem is that idValue  comes as "{ MemberNum = 20044782604 }" instead of just the "20044782604". Please let me know how to resolve it.

Thanks

Comment: Replaced string idValue = id.ToString(); with string idValue = id.MemberNum;

Comment: That's an unnecessarily complex solution. You should fix the problem at its origin, in the query, and not work around the symptoms when you enumerate.

Answer (score 5):

That's because you are creating a new anonymous type with the MemberNum as a property. Just select it instead.

```
var memberIDs = from d in dependents
                select d.MemberNum;
```

This will yield an `IEnumerable<int>` instead of an `IEnumerable<AnonymousType>` (assuming `MemberNum` is of type int).